chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter returns 404
we use https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|5|808000|000000|FFFF00 for pin-generation.
since a few days we got an 404 response ...
i found already this topic: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/251700701 but it is about qr-code-generation.
does the generation of map pins no longer work? has the api been switched off?
try to get a pin-image, get an 404 error

Google has deprecated and retired the chart API.
Please find the alternative i.e. https://quickchart.io/
You can find the further details on
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/251700701

Hello, how did you use it in JS code?

Use this URL to get cluster image:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/refs/heads/gh-pages/images/m1.png


You can replace that URL with this one:
https://www.google.com/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/spotlight/spotlight_pin_v4_outline-2-medium.png,assets/icons/spotlight/spotlight_pin_v4-2-medium.png,assets/icons/spotlight/spotlight_pin_v4_dot-2-medium.png&highlight=c5221f,ea4335,b31412?scale=1

